# why @Factory with @DataProvider cannot run on parallel?

Tags: java, testng

This always works sequentially. Why Parallel true isn't working here??  If I made a test with dataProvider "data", it works smoothly.

```
public class ExampleTestCase {
    @DataProvider(name = "data", parallel = true)
    public static Iterator<Object[]> getData() {
        List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

        data.add(new Object[]{"Apple"});
        data.add(new Object[]{"Banana");

        return data.iterator();
    }

    @Factory(dataProvider = "data")
    public static Object[] createExampleClass(String s) {
        return new Object[]{new ExampleTestCase(s)};
    }


}
```